# Excluding objects when print_r()ing variables in a custom logger

Tags: php, error-logging

I have Logger-Class which is logging everything.  Objects will be logged with print_r to a human-readable state.  My Problem is that I have a big MVC-Object. Everytime an Exception or Error occurs, the MVC-Object will also be printed in the Log by print_r.  This results in a very very long Logfile that is not really friendly to read.

I tried to set a `__toString()` method to my MVC-Class but this don't work.  I also get the complete MVC-Object in Log.  The MVC is a Singleton and is referenced on every Object.  So to simple exclude the Object before it cames into the print_r is not that easy.

Is there any way to exclude Objects from print_r?

My Methods:

LOG-Class errorHandler-Method:

```
public static function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $vars) {
                //If @ is set, don't do anything!
                if(error_reporting() === 0) {
                        return;
                }

                //Get StackTrace with low memory usage ;)
                $e = new Exception();
                $stackStr = $e->getTraceAsString();

                //Build ErrorMessage for Log
                $message =      'File: '.$errfile.' - L: '.$errline."\n".
                                'Code: '.$errno."\n".
                                'Message: '.$errstr."\n".
                                'Vars: '.print_r($vars, true)."\n".
                                'Stacktrace: '.$stackStr;
                self::error($message);
        }
```

LOG-Class exceptionHandler-Method:

```
public static function exceptionHandler(Exception $e) {
        $message =      get_class($e).': '.$e->getMessage()."\n".
                        'File: '.$e->getFile().' - L: '.$e->getLine()."\n".
                        'Code: '.$e->getCode()."\n".
                        'Message: '.$e->getMessage()."\n".
                        'Stacktrace: '.$e->getTraceAsString();
        self::error($message);
}
```

LOG-Class error-Method:

```
public static function error($data, $file='system.log') {
        $config = Megaira_PropertyConfiguration::getInstance();
        switch($config->get('LOG_MODE')) {
                case'DEEPDEBUG':
                case'ERROR':
                case'WARNING':
                case'INFO':
                case'DEBUG':
                        self::writeToLog('ERROR', $data, $file);
                        break;
        }
}
```

LOG-Class writeToLog-Method:

```
private static function writeToLog($mode='', $text='', $file=''){
        if(!is_string($text) && !is_numeric($text)) {
                $text = print_r($text, true);
        }
        $config = Megaira_PropertyConfiguration::getInstance();
        if(!$config->get('LOGGINGACTIVE')) { return; }
        self::writeLineToFile($mode, $text, $file);
}
```

Setup the Error- and Exception-handler:

```
        //Set Error and Exception Handler
        set_error_handler(array(new LOG(), 'errorHandler'));
        set_exception_handler(array(new LOG(), 'exceptionHandler'));
```

Thanks

Some Testing:

```
public static function print_r_filtered($object, $ret=false) {
                $filtered = array(
                        'Megaira_MVC'
                );
                $text = print_r($object, true);
                foreach($filtered as $filter) {
                        $search = '#('.$filter.'\sObject)\n(\s+)\).*?\n\2\)\n#s';
                        $replace = "$1";
                        $text = preg_replace($search, $replace, $text);
                }
                if($ret)
                        return $text;
                echo $text;
        }
```

Did not work. Maybe RegEx fail?

Solution:

It was a Design flaw. The errorHandler is Logging all Objects that are used on the place the error occurs. So in the index.php are the following code:

```
$mvc = Megaira_MVC::getInstance();
```

So this peace of code produced a logging of the Var `$mvc` with print_r through the errorHandler in LOG-Class.

Conclusion for me: Don't use Variables on big Singleton-Objects or use unset() if the Var is not needed anymore.

Comment: Oh my god. There is a little bit time gone since i had written this Class. Here i can see any ugly (not performant) code. Ignore this "ugly" code ^^. Just focus the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__toString()` is called, when the object is casted to a string. You may try something like

```
$objectString = method_exists($object, '__toString')
              ? (string) $object
              : print_r($object, true);
```

Use `is_object()` to find out, if a value is an object or not.

At all

```
$string = !is_object($value) || method_exists($value, '__toString')
        ? (string) $value
        : print_r($value, true);
```

Comment: Right. But the MVC is a Singleton and is referenced on every Object.

Comment: Nice copy&paste comments, but whats the matter?

Comment: Everyone is telling the same with other words. Should i answer the same with other words everytime?

Comment: Don't know ^^ But I don't see the problem. That you have a singleton (as a kind of god-object?) seems to me more like a design flaw of the architecture you're using. With `to_string()` you can at least reduce the output you will receive from this.

Comment: The MVC-Object is a Singleton. I have a Basic Class that is extended on every other Class. This Class has Methods like getCache getMVC getConfig. On first call to any of this Methods the returned Object will be cached in current Object as Reference.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap print_r with your own function that checks whether the provided data includes any objects, using the `is_object()` function.  Similarly, you could use `is_a()` if you only want to exclude **certain** classes of objects.

Comment: Right. But the MVC is a Singleton and is referenced on every Object.

Comment: Please show some code so we can see more about how/what you are sending to print_r()

Comment: Check out this example of a function someone wrote to remove (hide) nested objects:  http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#87705

Answer (score 0):

as a html solution you can use:

```
<pre><?=print_r(log_content);?></pre>
```

to display your log file better. I am displaying the log files in this way.

Comment: using tail -f with "ccze" is much better i think ;-) but thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if (is_object( $foo ))
{
  print_r( $foo->__toString() );
} else {
  print_r( $foo );
}
```

Comment: Right. But the MVC is a Singleton and is referenced on every Object.

Answer (score 0):

If you can alter the Logger class, you can check for the class befpre you print it:

```
if(!($var instanceof HeavyMVCObject)){
    print_r($var);
}
```

Comment: Right. But the MVC is a Singleton and is referenced on every Object.